# Facebook graph API not giving result to until date

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i want to get page insights data from 2014-08-01 to 2014-08-31 but problem is i am getting data to 2014-08-30 date only. if i am giving until date 2014-08-30 it will give me data to 
2014-08-29. whatever i give date it show me result of until date - 1.

`$get_data = array(
            'access_token' =>'my access token'
            'period' => 'day',

            'since' => '2014-08-01',
            'until' => '2014-08-31',
        );
    $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/'page  id'/insights/?'.http_build_query($get_data));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output
            $oResult2 = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);
            $oResult2 = json_decode($oResult2);
    foreach($oResult2->data as $oData)
        {
        print_r($oData);
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve solve my problem... i have to pass date like this

```
'since' => '2014-08-01 00:00:00',
'until' => '2014-08-31 23:59:59',
```